# Creating a large database from many files with pandas

Tags: python, database, numpy, pandas

I have many files (~2,000,000) generated by another program that I need to extract data from. These files have common indices with a different value for different methods, I am not sure how to phrase this well so here is a three dimensional example:

```
[x1,y1,z1,method1]
[x1,y1,z1,method2]
[x2,y2,z2,method1]
[x2,y2,z2,method2]
```

Ultimately what I would like to have is a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    x   y   z  method1  method2 ... methodn
0  x1  y1  z1     data     data        data
1  x2  y2  z2     data     data        data
2  x3  y3  z3      NaN     data        data
3  x4  y4  z4     data      NaN        data
...
n  xn  yn  zn     data      NaN        NaN
```

There will be some holes in the method and the data is not aligned.

The following shows the pseudocode:

```
file_list=glob.glob('/scratch/project/*')

method1_list=[]
method2_list=[]
...
methodn_list=[]

#Obtain data in the correct list
for outfile in file_list:
    indices=(#function that obtains indices)
    data=(#function that obtains primary data)

    if method1: method1_list.append([indices,data])
    elif method2: method2_list.append([indices,data])
    ...
    else methodn: methodn_list.append([indices,data])

#Convert list to dataframe
method1_pd=pd.DataFrame(method1_list,columns[indices,method1])
method2_pd=pd.DataFrame(method2_list,columns[indices,method1])
...
methodn_pd=pd.DataFrame(methodn_list,columns[indices,method1])

#Apply multi index
method1=method1.set_index(indices)
method2=method2.set_index(indices)
...
methodn=methodn.set_index(indices)

#Combine data    
out=method1.combine_first(method2)
out=out.combine_first(method3)
...
out=out.combine_first(methodn)
```

This works really well, however as the number of the methods is growing this is becoming fairly tedious to write and seems rather unpythonic. So I have the following questions:

- Is there a better way to create a DataFrame in this way? Everything after the for loop is already wrapped in a definition, but it did not help readability here. I still have to state each method three times.
- Is there an easy way to omit already read files if I would like to update the dataset?
- Is there a better way to align pandas data in this way?

Comment: a couple of questions: approx how many methods r there uniquely, do u know them apriori, how many rows total are u expecting, are u appending (eg building then adding data say tomorrow), what is the end goal of this frame (eg lookup table, computation)?

Comment: I know the methods a priori (20-30 in total), in total there will be somewhere around 200,000 rows, and the end goal is to run statistics, produce datasets, and also provide a lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work, though depending on how your data is actually constructed. If you can provide a sample, might help. It assumes that your indices is known (or computed
as you go)

```
from collections import defaultdict
file_list = glob.glob('/scratch/project/*')

methods = defaultdict([])
for outfile in file_list:
    #indices = (#function that obtains indices)
    #data    = (#function that obtains primary data)

    methods[method].append([indices,data])

frames = [ DataFrame(method_list,columns[indices,method]) 
         for method, method_list in methods.items() ]

# concat
combine_frame = pd.concat(frames,axis=1)

# set your combined index
result = combine_frame.set_index(indicies)
```

Comment: The data will not be aligned so a simple concat will not be enough. Although if you create the frames in such a way its a simple matter to loop through setting indices and combine_first. I was really hoping there was a simple pandas way to to do this.

Comment: just reindex the frames before you concat in that case

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps concat every file/frame and create a pivot table from the final DataFrame?

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""\
x,y,z,data
x1,y1,z1,1
x2,y2,z2,1
"""), sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""\
x,y,z,data
x1,y1,z1,2
x2,y2,z2,2
"""), sep=',')
df3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""\
x,y,z,data
x3,y2,z2,3
"""), sep=',')
df1['method'] = 'method1'
df2['method'] = 'method2'
df3['method'] = 'method3'
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

In [17]: df.pivot_table(rows=['x', 'y', 'z'], cols='method', values='data',
...                     aggfunc='first')
Out[17]: 
method    method1  method2  method3
x  y  z                            
x1 y1 z1        1        2      NaN
x2 y2 z2        1        2      NaN
x3 y2 z2      NaN      NaN        3

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
    x   y   z  data   method
0  x1  y1  z1     1  method1
1  x2  y2  z2     1  method1
0  x1  y1  z1     2  method2
1  x2  y2  z2     2  method2
0  x3  y2  z2     3  method3
```

Comment: Ah, the pivot_table +1. I will end up using a hybrid of the two responses, but the defaultdict idea handles the most pressing concern.